# Vlookup excel search and match cell and auto populate on sheet1

Tags: excel, vlookup

In cell G9 on sheet1 I want to write say 100 and from **sheet2** search C column that matches 100 which would be 012 into cell C13 on **sheet1** and also put column F value in **sheet2** into cell C9 on **sheet1**.

**sheet 2**

```
 B       C         F
100     012   10 Station street
200     045   20 Bolton road
300     062   26 french close
400     023   19 apple street
```

How would I do this with VLOOKUP?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? This question doesn't show research effort.

Comment: Hi I have searched lots of sites and downloaded a few examples but don't seem to be able to get it to work. I was hoping it would be nice and easy. I can do it no problem with VBA but wanted to get it to work using a formula. Trying to save my self a little time everyday at work not having to search and copy /paste

Comment: Please include some code that doesn't work and we will do our best to detect the error and hopefully find a solution.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying something like this with sheet 2 called SCHEDULE
     =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!G9,SCHEDULE!A:D,2,FALSE)

Comment: =VLOOKUP(Sheet1!G9,SCHEDULE!A:C+SCHEDULE!A:D,2,FALSE) this also returns no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=VLOOKUP(G9,Schedule!A:C,3,FALSE)` in C9 on sheet 1.
`=VLOOKUP(G9,Schedule!A:C,2,FALSE)` in C13 on sheet 1.
Type 100 into G9 on sheet 1 with your data in another sheet named 'Schedule'

Remember vlookup will only find a match if the format matches.

Comment: Thanks I used this and it worked perfect for what I needed. Cheers for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C4,MATCH(Sheet1!G9,Sheet1!B1:B4))
```

That will get you started on the first part, I’m not sure what you mean on the second.
`Index(sheet1!c1:c4)` is the answer you’re looking for.
`Match(sheet1!g9,sheet1!b1:b4)` is “100” or what you want to look up and where that “100” is located.

Comment: Thanks for the help I am going to have a look at Match for future use.

Comment: @kiper3000 make sure you look at index match together, just index won’t help much but together it’s a much more powerful function than vlookup. I was just saying index(whatever) is where the answer would be located and match is how it finds it. Not sure if i conveyed that correctly.